# JPA Inheritance is not DRY

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I've got inheritance working but it's not very DRY.  Every new `bolt` type I have to repeat code. Best to show my classes then explain further

My parent class for a `BoltSpec` (Dimensions pertaining to a fastener)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BoltSpecs")
@IdClass(BoltSpecCK.class)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="boltType" )
public abstract class BoltSpec implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String size;

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EnumBoltType boltType;

    private BigDecimal basic_major_diameter = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

and my `EnumBoltType`

```
public enum EnumBoltType {
    CYLINDER_HEAD_CAP_SCREW("CYLINDER HEAD CAP SCREW", EnumHeadType.CYL),
    HEX_CAP_SCREW("HEX CAP SCREW", EnumHeadType.HEX),
    HEAVY_HEX_CAP_SCREW("HEAVY HEX CAP SCREW", EnumHeadType.HEX),
    HEX_BOLT("HEX BOLT", EnumHeadType.HEX),
    HEAVY_HEX_BOLT("HEAVY HEX BOLT", EnumHeadType.HEX),
    FLAT_COUNTERSUNK_HEAD_CAP_SCREW("FLAT COUNTERSUNK HEAD CAP SCREW", EnumHeadType.CONE);
```

I then have to have duplicate classes, i.e. `HexCapScrew`, `HeavyHexCapScrew` etc and `HexCapScrewSpec`, `HeavyHexCapScrewSpec`, etc even though they have similar `BoltSpec` Properties (not numerical values)

```
public class HexCapScrew extends Bolt {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static HexCapScrewSpec spec;
    public HexCapScrew() {
        super(spec);
    }
}

public class HeavyHexCapScrew extends Bolt {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static HeavyHexCapScrewSpec spec;
    public HeavyHexCapScrew () {
        super(spec);
    }
}
```

...

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("HEX_CAP_SCREW")
public class HexCapScrewSpec extends BoltSpec implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HexCapScrewSpec() {
        super();
    }

    private BigDecimal flat_diameter = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    ...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("HEAVY_HEX_CAP_SCREW")
public class HeavyHexCapScrewSpec extends BoltSpec implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HeavyHexCapScrewSpec() {
        super();
    }

    private BigDecimal flat_diameter = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    ...
```

this spec is different

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FLAT_COUNTERSUNK_HEAD_CAP_SCREW")
public class FlatHeadCapScrewSpec extends BoltSpec implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FlatHeadCapScrewSpec() {
        super();
    }

    private BigDecimal cone_angle = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    ...
```

here is some sample import.sql data

```
insert into BoltSpecs (basic_size, basic_major_diameter, boltType, flat_diameter) 
    values ('2-3/4', '2.75',  'HEX_CAP_SCREW',       '3.988')
    values ('3',     '3',     'HEX_CAP_SCREW',       '4.35')
    values ('3/8',   '0.375', 'HEAVY_HEX_CAP_SCREW', '0.669')

insert into BoltSpecs (basic_size, basic_major_diameter, boltType, cone_angle) 
    values ('2-3/4', '2.75',  'FLAT_COUNTERSUNK_HEAD_CAP_SCREW',       '39.77')
```

I have in the frontend a dropdown menu where the user chooses the bolt type and need to use the applicable bolt specs.  I don't want to modify my import.sql and put the bolt head type.  I run the risk of putting say `CONE` for a `HEX` type bolt.  Is there a way to do  multiple `DiscriminatorValue`s?  Like:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("HEX_CAP_SCREW, HEAVY_HEX_CAP_SCREW, HEX_BOLT, HEAVY_HEX_BOLT")
public class BoltSpecHexHead extends BoltSpec implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BoltSpecHexHead () {
        super();
    }

    private BigDecimal flat_diameter = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

...

```
public class BoltHexHead extends Bolt {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static BoltSpecHexHead spec;
    public BoltSpecHexHead () {
        super(spec);
    }
}
```

Or how can I ping off the EnumHeadType as the discriminator value?  Specifications are similar between bolts with similar heads (EnumHeadType.CYL, HEX and CONE)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve a solution using `@DiscriminatorFormula`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BoltSpecs")
@IdClass(BoltSpecCK.class)
//@DiscriminatorColumn(name="boltType" )
@DiscriminatorFormula("case when boltType in ('CYLINDER_HEAD_CAP_SCREW') then 'HEX' 
   when boltType in ('HEX_CAP_SCREW','HEAVY_HEX_CAP_SCREW','HEX_BOLT','HEAVY_HEX_BOLT') then 'HEX' 
   when boltType in ('FLAT_COUNTERSUNK_HEAD_CAP_SCREW') then 'CONE' end")

public abstract class BoltSpec implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why *can't* you use the same class (let's say `Bolt`) for all of these? They look similar, they share the same properties, does their behavior change? If so, then just use a decorator based on the bolt type around an instance.

Comment: The bolt's specifications (dimensions of the bolt's head) differ between types of bolts. boltSpec is a property of bolt.  So I need a HexHead Bolt, a PanHeadBolt, a socketCapHeadBolt, etc.  So I don't know what you are really asking, but I have things working using the discriminatorformula.